# Clock based in real time

Tags: javascript, datetime, prompt, alerts

I have a game that I am making in the style of ZORK, and it has constant alerts and prompts, and includes a time that you need to last to win it.

Since it has alerts and prompts to play the game, I cannot use a set timeout to run the clock, so I created a clock based on real time, but am having some trouble getting it to work.

Here's the code

```
var now = new Date();

var stS = now.getSeconds();
var stM = now.getMinutes();
var stH = now.getHours();



function getElapsedTime() {

setTimeout(function () {




var reS = now.getSeconds();
var reM = now.getMinutes();
var reH = now.getHours();

var elapS = reS - stS;
var elapM = reM - stM;
var elapH = reH - stH;

if (elapM < 0) {
    reM = reM + 60;
    elapM = reM - stM;

}

if (elapS < 0) {
    reS = reS + 60;
    elapS = reS - stS;
}


alert(elapS);
alert(elapM);
alert(elapH);
}, 10000);

}
getElapsedTime();
```

Edit:
I run it in jsfiddle, but it returns the alert saying that no time has passed when it should say ten seconds have passed.
http://jsfiddle.net/t57wsrx8/

Comment: What is not working? Could you show us an example in codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: What's not working? is it giving you incorrect output? is the day wrong? is the time backwards?

Comment: I should have been more clear. When I run it jsfiddle, it give the information but it says that no time has passed. http://jsfiddle.net/t57wsrx8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same `now` that you started off with 10 seconds earlier. A `Date` object keeps the time it was given. It doesn't automatically change as time passes. You need to instantiate a new `now`:

```
function getElapsedTime() {

    setTimeout(function () {

        var now = new Date();

        var reS = now.getSeconds();
        var reM = now.getMinutes();
        var reH = now.getHours();

        var elapS = reS - stS;
        var elapM = reM - stM;
        var elapH = reH - stH;

        if (elapM < 0) {
            reM = reM + 60;
            elapM = reM - stM;
        }

        if (elapS < 0) {
            reS = reS + 60;
            elapS = reS - stS;
        }

        alert(elapS);
        alert(elapM);
        alert(elapH);
    }, 10000);
}
```

Note that you can calculate time spans more cleanly if you treat dates as numbers:

```js
var start = +new Date();

function getElapsedTime() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var elapsed = +new Date() - start;
        
        var elapS = Math.floor(elapsed /    1000) % 60;
        var elapM = Math.floor(elapsed /   60000) % 60;
        var elapH = Math.floor(elapsed / 3600000) % 24;

        alert(elapS);
        alert(elapM);
        alert(elapH);
    }, 10000);
}
getElapsedTime();
```